# Keeping subnav items in a static position

Tags: css

I'm trying to build a subnav using css3. The one thing I can't work out to do is keep the subnav in the same place.

Similar to http://www.laingorourke.com/.

How do I keep the subnav items at a fixed place regardless of where you hover over the top nav items?

I've created a jsfiddle to show what I'm trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/jimbeeer/F9PNr/

The subnav items css is on line 10:

```
ul#css3menu1 ul{
display:none;
position:absolute;
float:left;
left:0;
top:100%;
padding:0px;
margin:0px 0 0 0px;
z-index:10;
background-color:#093365;
width:1000px;}
```

I'm pretty sure it's quite easy but I can't for the life of me work it out!

Thanks in advance.

-James

Answer (score 0):

Just do some little changes to your code:-

```
ul#css3menu1 ul {
    background-color: #093365;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top:100%; //Remove This
    width:1000px; //Remove This
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that didn't work at all. I've updated the jsfiddle with your code but the subnav items are still appearing relative to the holding ul.I'm trying to get them a fixed position and a fixed width, regardless of the hover on the parent li.